# Searching for hundreds of files on a server

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I have a list of 577 image files that I need to search for on a large server. I am no expert when it comes to bash so the best I could do myself was 577 lines of this:

```
find /source/directory -type f -iname "alternate1_1052956.tif" -exec cp {} /dest/directory \;
```

...repeating this line for each file name. It works... but it's *unbelievably* slow because it searches the entire server for one file and then moves on to the next line, but each search could take 20 minutes. I left this overnight and it only found 29 of them by the morning which is just way too slow. It could take two weeks at that rate to find all of these.

I've tried separating each line with `-o` as an OR separator in the hopes that it would search once for 577 files but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I also tried using the .txt file I have of the file names as a basis for the search but couldn't get that to work either. Unfortunately I don't have the paths for these files, only the basenames.

Comment: Make one list of all the files on the server, grep the 577 files from that list, make a for loop to copy those files where you want them.

Comment: Why `-o -iname` doesn't work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all `.tif` files

```
find /source/directory -type f -name "*.tif" -exec cp {} /dest/directory \;
#                                     ^
```

Comment: This is all but regex here

Comment: No, I need to search for the specific file names. There are hundreds of thousands of images and I need 577 of them.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, use the `mdfind` command that will look for the filename in the SpotLight index. This is very fast as it is only an index lookup, just like the `locate` command in Linux:

```
cp $(mdfind alternate1_1052956.tif) /dest/directory
```

If you have all the filenames in a file (one line per file) use xargs

```
xargs -L 1 -I {} cp $(mdfind {}) /dest/directory < file_with_list
```

Comment: I tried your `xargs`, I think the problem with it is that I'm not specifying what the source dir is. I CD'ed to the dir I want to search, then ran this, but it started to copy files from /Library/Applications and all kinds of other random places. The list of files I have does not include paths, just the basename, so is there a way for me to specify the source dir as well?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with all filenames, then write a loop which runs through that file and executes command in background.

Note, that this will take a lot of memory, as you will be executing this simultaneously multiple times. So make sure you have enough memory for this.

```
while read -r line; do
find /source/directory -type f -iname "$line" -exec cp {} /dest/directory \ &;
done < input.file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few assumption made in this answer. You have a list of all `577` file names, let's call it, `inputfile.list`. There are no whitespaces in the file names. Following may work:

```
$ cat findcopy.sh
#!/bin/bash

cmd=$(
echo -n 'find /path/to/directory -type f '
readarray -t filearr < inputfile.list  # Read the list to an array
n=0
for f in "${filearr[@]}" # Loop over the array and print -iname 
do
    (( n > 0 )) && echo "-o -iname ${f}"  || echo "-iname ${f}"
    ((n++))
done
echo -n ' | xargs -I {} cp {} /path/to/destination/'
)
eval $cmd
```

execute: `./findcopy.sh`

Note for `MacOS`. It doesn't have `readarray`. Instead use any other simple method to feed the list into array, for example,

```
filearr=($(cat inputfile.list))
```

Comment: I gave this a try. I get error `line 15: readarray: command not found`, I believe referring to the last line. This does copy files, but it starts copying all files from /dest instead of searching for the specific files in the list.

Comment: Didn't realize that you had a  `MacOSX`. See my updated notes about that.